# custom layout not rendering for overridden login method

Tags: magento-1.9

Please some one dont close this as duplicate, no answers fixing my issue:

Im trying to create a new page in which login and register come together and will have custom fields.

Below is the my folder structure:

```
app
    - code
        - local
            - Php
                - Customer
                    - etc
                    - controllers
                    - Model

app
    - design
        - frontend
            - default
                - php
                    - layout
                    - template
```

Below is the module config file:

app/code/local/php/Customer/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Php_Customer>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Php_Customer>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <php_customer before="Mage_Customer">Php_Customer</php_customer>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <customer module="Php_Customer">
                    <file>php_customer.xml</file>
                </customer>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Below is account controller:

app/code/local/php/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php

```
<?php

require_once 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';
class Php_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{
    public function loginAction(){
        die('Php Overriden');
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    } 
}
```

Below is the layout config:

app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/php_customer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <php_customer_account_login>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="module/ablock" name="login" template="popup_login.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </php_customer_account_login>
</layout>
```

below is the template file:

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/popup_login.phtml

```
<p>HTML Rendered Successfully</p>
```

When I echo something in the controller its printing on the screen, So I understood module added. but the phtml file is not rendering.

Below is exception log file:

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Php_Customer_Block_Login' in D:\wamp\www\promo\app\Mage.php:595
```

No error log captured.

Comment: check the error log and past it too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<block type="module/ablock" name="login" template="popup_login.phtml" />
```

change it

```
<block type="core/template" name="login" template="popup_login.phtml" />
```

if it is working. then create your block.

Comment: whats the difference between these two?

Comment: this is a big difference. this is core core/template block. other will be created by you. and i think you don't create the block and extend from that block.

Comment: yes I haven't created any Php/Customer/Block Its working after changing module/ablock to core/template